# Mistake in simplification of large polynomial inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

We are to solve for $p$, and the inequality to simplify is

$$10p^3(1-p)^2 + 5p^4(1-p) + p^5 - 3p^2(1-p) - p^3 > 0$$

On the next line of the textbook, the author simplifies this expression to

$$3(p-1)^2(2p-1) > 0 \implies p > \frac{1}{2}$$

Since no work was shown, I attempted to reach the same result but got

$$3(p-1)^2(2p-1) \cdot \mathbb{p^2} > 0$$

Have I made a mistake in my work, or are the answers possibly equivalent? Might there be any reason to leave out the $p^2$ factor from the inequality I reached?

Comment: What you did is correct. The author must be assuming that $p > 0$ and then divides out the $p^2$ term, which is also correct.

Comment: @Amzoti I think $p\neq 0$ suffices

Comment: For the strict inequality to be true, p cannot be zero. Similarly p cannot be 1. The rest follows...

Comment: @Amzoti thank you. At the moment it's not obvious to me why we may divide out the $p^2$ if $p > 0$. Maybe tomorrow I'll see why, then write an answer to my own question.

Comment: @Amzoti, let me see if I have this correct. If we assume $p > 0$ then it is correct to divide $p^2 > 0$ from the inequality because the solution to $p^2 \gt 0 \implies p \gt 0$ is redundant information; we already know $p \gt 0$.

Comment: @chubakueno, it is not at first completely obvious why $p \ne 0$ suffices to divide $p^2$ from the inequality when solving for $p$. Except for possibly generally (or incorrectly) to say that for any variable $x \ne 0$ we can divide $x^2$ from a polynomial inequality $f(x) \gt 0$ since $\large \frac{1}{x^{2}} \normalsize f(x) \gt \large \frac{1}{x^{2}} \normalsize 0 \implies \large \frac{1}{x^{2}} \normalsize f(x) \gt 0$.

Comment: @Necron You can **always** divide both sides of an inequality by a positive value. If $x\neq 0$, then $x^2>0$. (Because $x^2\ge 0$ is a tautology in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @Necron: that is correct in the approach. We need for $p >1/2$ and the $p^2$ term does not matter. WLOG, we can just say $p>0$. We could have been exact and stated that when $p > 1/2$ and still divided out the $p^2$ term based on this.

Answer (score 0):

The original expression factorizes as $4p^2(p-1)(p-3)(p-\frac14)>0.$ So $\frac14<p<1$ or $p>3.$

Comment: It may help to show more, complete work on how to reach this result.

Comment: @Necron: The $p^2$ factor is obvious. Notice that $$p^5-p^3=p^3(p^2-1)=p^2\cdot p(p-1)(p+1),$$and you can then see the $p-1$ factor. What remains is a quadratic in $p$, which factorizes as $(p-3)(4p-1).$